# try-with-resources and method chaining

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I want to use try-with-resources with method chaining:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(entity.getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
  String page = s.next();
  return page;
}
```

I am getting a "Resource Leak:  is never closed" on the `new Scanner(...)`

I can work around it (see below) but it looks like an overkill. Any suggestion?

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
try (
     Scanner one = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
     Scanner s = one.useDelimiter("\\A")
    ) {
  String page = s.next();
  return page;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  That "Resource Leak" warning is a flaw in your IDE or analysis tool.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(entity.getContent())) {
  s.useDelimiter("\\A");
  return s.next();
}
```

In the method chaining version (and in your revised code), the (EDIT) IDE thinks that (/EDIT) the JVM creates two Scanner objects. But you can just ignore the return value from useDelimiter() (since it is just the same Scanner).

If you are really sold on method chaining, you could try this

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(entity.getContent())) {
  return s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
}
```

Comment: It absolutely does not create two Scanner objects.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, it doesn't help to ignore output from useDelimiter(), but I see that it helps in Eclipse. In IntelliJ, you can configure instances returned from Scanner::useDelimiter to be ignored under Settings > Inspections :)